How could I speed up this tensor product?
I have to take tensor products of lists of tensors and I want to include the possibility of tensors whose components have high working precision. The tensors are all totally symmetric, so the first thing I thought was Symmetrized array, but it makes things worse somehow. Here is a simple example (Note that how I generate these lists is totally irrelevant, the problem appears once you start using the lists, this is just a "shift+enter" type of code.)
list1 = Table[
SymmetrizedArray[
    MapThread[Rule,{SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[{4,4,4}, Symmetric[All]], RandomReal[{10,100}, {20}, WorkingPrecision->35]}],
    {4,4,4}, Symmetric[All]
],
{40}
]; 

list2 = Table[
SymmetrizedArray[
    MapThread[Rule,{SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[{4,4,4,4}, Symmetric[All]], RandomReal[{10,100}, {35}, WorkingPrecision->35] }],
    {4,4,4,4}, Symmetric[All]
],
{40}
];

list1Normal = GetNormal/@list1;
list2Normal = GetNormal/@list2;

The function "GetNormal"gives me the normal expression corresponding to the tensor but with zeros in the position of linearly dependent components(again, another "shift+enter"code):
GetNormal[tensor_]:= Block[{dims = Dimensions@tensor, dummy2 = ConstantArray[0,Dimensions@tensor]},
    Do[
    dummy2[[Evaluate@(Sequence@@i)]] = tensor[[Sequence@@i]],
    {i, SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[dims, Symmetric[All]]}
    ];
    dummy2
]

Summary:
-> list1 has 40 totally symmetric tensors of rank-3 and list2 is 40 totally symmetric tensors of rank-4 the tensors in these lists are in Mathematica's "SymmetrizedArray" representation.
-> list1Normal and list2Normal contains the same tensors of list1 and list2 but they are in their normal expression forms, with zeros in the position of linearly dependent components.
The problem appears when I take the tensor products:
In[192]:= MapThread[
    Outer[Times, #1, #2]&,{list1, list2}
];//AbsoluteTiming

Out[192]= {0.722444, Null}

In[194]:= MapThread[
    Outer[Times, #1, #2]&,{list1Normal, list2Normal}
];//AbsoluteTiming

Out[194]= {0.15521, Null}

SymmetrizedArray is actually slower?? Is there anything I can do to speed up this operation? Maybe bring it a little closer to to PackedArrays and machine precision which are obviously way faster:
In[195]:= packedlist1  = ToPackedArray@(N/@list1Normal);
packedlist2 = ToPackedArray@(N/@list2Normal);
PackedArrayQ@packedlist1
MapThread[
    Outer[Times, #1, #2]&,{packedlist1, packedlist2}
];//AbsoluteTiming

Out[197]= True

Out[198]= {0.001203, Null}
```


On my machine the following is about 4-5 times faster and leads to the same result as MapThread[Outer[Times, #1, #2] &, {list1, list2}]:
ArrayReshape[
 MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {Flatten /@ Normal[list1],Flatten /@ Normal[list2]}],
 Join[Dimensions[list1], Rest[Dimensions[list2]]]
 ]

An even faster way by getting a bit low-level
Well, handling symmetrized arrays does have some advantage: A fully symmetric tensor of rank k can be stored in roughly only 1/k! of the memory it would take to store a full unsymmetric tensor. And also all sorts of operations on the entries would also require less time. The problem with SymmetrizedArray is that it is designed to handle all sorts the symmetries. Typically that happens at the cost of some efficiency. You tensors in list1 and list2 have the same symmetry though. So the overhead to handle the symmetries is only needed once. Moreover, you have fully symmetric tensors, which are particularly easy to deal with:
Let's grab a prototype from each list:
a = list1[[1]];
apat = Keys[a["ArrayRules"]];
aval = Values[a["ArrayRules"]];

b = list2[[1]];
bpat = Keys[b["ArrayRules"]];
bval = Values[b["ArrayRules"]];

Now look at this:
c = TensorProduct[a, b];
cpat = Keys[c["ArrayRules"]];
cval = Values[c["ArrayRules"]];

Max[Abs[Flatten[KroneckerProduct[aval, bval]] - cval]]


0.*10^-31

So we can simply let KroneckerProduct act on the lists of values (with the internal ordering). The pattern of the tensor product needs to be computed only once (and is stored in cpat). So, should we ever need the thing as SymmetrizedArray, we can construct it with
toSymmetrizedArray = SymmetrizedArray[Thread[cpat -> #], Dimensions[c], c["Symmetry"]]&;

toSymmetrizedArray[Flatten[KroneckerProduct[aval, bval]]]

That allows us to compute the values for all tensor products very, very efficiently:
First we extract all the values. Actually, I would suggest to never generate all the SymmetrizedArrays in the first place.
values1 = Values[#["ArrayRules"]] & /@ list1;
values2 = Values[#["ArrayRules"]] & /@ list2;

The values of all the tensor products can be obtained now much, much faster with this  (it's more than 100 times faster than the original approach):
values3 = Flatten[
     MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {values1, values2}],
     {{1}, {2, 3}}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First


0.00291552

vs.
list3 = MapThread[Outer[Times, #1, #2] &, {list1, list2}]; // RepeatedTiming // First


0.434948

Should you ever need the k-th product tensor as SymmetrizedArray array, you can do
toSymmetrizedArray[ values3[[k]]] ]

But I would recommend to never do that as constructing the SymmetrizedArray is horribly expensive:
toSymmetrizedArray /@ values3; // RepeatedTiming // First 


0.413193

So it is basically at all the cost of the original approach. This is because it does all sorts of checks and the actual symmetrization again and then builds the structure of the tensors -- which we actually know already.

That is very good! If I understood it correctly you transforms tensors -> vectors then takes the tensor product and restore the full shape. Do you know if that is a general strategy? That is, given a tensor operation is better to find it the equivalent vector operation and restore the tensor at the end? It looked like the system is faster when dealing with a vector than with a tensor with the same number of components.

I know experience that KroneckerProductis implemented quite well and array reshape operations tend to be quite inexpensive. (I think they might not even involve a copy operatoration). Apart fromt that, the strategy here is to avoid overly fancy data structures that have not been fully optimized. Symmetrized arrays are unfortunately seldemly a boost to performance.

Very nice, Thanks.

You're welcome.

like nathan hale "I only regret that I have but one upvote to give to your answer." Seriously, this really good, detail I don't actually generate symmetrized arrays in my code, I just posted them here to see whether there was a better way to use them. Your method is very good I believe I can adapt it to my actual problem.

Awesome. I am glad to be of help.
